# errorLoading message on abort select2

Tags: jquery-select2

It's look like when you are aborting a query on a dropdown list with an ajax behaviour the errorLaoding ('The results could not be loaded.') show up on the results options.

I dug in the code and I found that the message is trigger by the line 3476 (version 4.0.3) fix since the 4.0.6 rc1

```
self.trigger('results:message', {
    message: 'errorLoading'
});
```

But is was not prevented by the abort test just above

```
// Attempt to detect if a request was aborted
// Only works if the transport exposes a status property
if ($request.status && $request.status === '0') {
      return;
}
```

because the abort status (jQuery 3.3.1 line 9028) is not a string but an interger and $request.status is not enough, so can we use that to correct this issue ?

```
if ($request.status !== undefined && $request.status === 0) {
      return;
}
```